# Hash key and value

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, hash

I'm curious of why hashing needs both hash key and hash value.

1. If a hash key was an int, hash key is changed in to a hash code which is the index of hashes. However, the hash value is the same as hash key isn't it? So, when I'm using a int for hash keys hash value isn't needed as a parameter (duplicate with hash key).
2. If I have a hash key as a string, hash key is also changed to a hash code. And then, a hash value is some number I want to match with the string?
   Or a pointer for the string?

I don't get why hash values are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first get some terminology straight since you appear to be confused regarding them<sup>1</sup>.

In hashing, there are really only two things, the item (from footnote, probably your hash value/key) and the hashcode. You pass the input item to a hashing function and get back a hashcode. That's the general case but make sure you've read the footnote - there may be valid reasons for distinguishing between a complete item and the key portion of it.

In terms of why you need the hash value as well as code, let's say, for example, you're keeping a record of all the super-intelligent, handsome people on the planet (along with their dog's names), and you therefore need to add the string `paxdiablo:lilly`.

So you throw that string into your hashing function and end up with a hashcode of 42 (calculated from just `paxdiablo`), so that's the bucket where it goes.

However, since the hashing function is almost invariably a many to one operation (many other strings will also hash to 42), there's no way to tell that it's actually `paxdiablo` in your data structure based on the hashcode alone.

In fact, my arch-nemesis `paxangelo`, who has a cat called, of all things, `fluffybunnykins`, is one of the dumbest, ugliest lifeforms you could ever hope not to meet, and also generates a hashcode of 42. So, when it comes to finding out who's in the 42 bucket, how are you going to tell the difference between the two unless the original string is in there?

The hashcode decides which bucket is used for an item, but you still have to actually *put* the item into the bucket.

---

<sup>1</sup> I tried for about ten minutes but I'm *still* not entirely happy with what I came up with. As best I can tell, you're using:

- hash value as the entire item to be stored.
- hash key to be that portion of the hash value used for hashing.
- hash value as the result of the hashing function.

I tend not to distinguish between the first two simply because there's not really anything to gain in my opinion. I generally pass an entire item to a hashing function but you *could* conceivably engineer a solution that only wants the key part, *especially* if you wanted to use a hashing function on different record layouts (with the key in a different position).

Comment: Then If i want to find paxdiablo in my hash. Do I search for the hash value..? which means there is some space saying paxdiablo == hash value is this right?

Comment: @양수현, if you want to find `paxdiablo`, you hash the string to get 42, then go to the #42 bucket and rummage through all the entries until you find it (or not, as the case may be).

Comment: I'm still not sure about the hash value, when I'm searching for paxdiablo. is the hash value paxdiablo then..?